# Use Hbc Twitter Stream without specifying any track terms

Tags: java, twitter, twitter-streaming-api, twitter-hbc

I followed the *Quickstart* from [HBC](https://github.com/twitter/hbc) and I managed to get some tweets from the Twitter Stream specifying some **track terms**, here is the code:

```
/** Declare the host you want to connect to, the endpoint, and authentication (basic auth or oauth) */
Hosts hosebirdHosts = new HttpHosts(Constants.STREAM_HOST);
StreamingEndpoint endpoint = new StatusesFilterEndpoint();
// Optional: set up some followings and track terms
List<Long> followings = Lists.newArrayList(1234L, 566788L);
List<String> terms = Lists.newArrayList("twitter", "api");
endpoint.followings(followings);
endpoint.trackTerms(terms);
```

Is it possible to get the twitter Stream with **Hbc** without specifying any track terms?
I simply tried to remove the line *"endpoint.trackTerms(terms);"* but doing so it doesn't work.
Help me! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It should work. I tried the example, and 'followed' myself and I received the Tweet I made whilst I was connected.

I suspect that the users you are following didn't have any activity whilst you were consuming the stream and that's why you didn't see any output - e.g. themselves Tweeting or somebody replying to one of their Tweets etc...

The [`follow` parameter](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/streaming-apis/parameters#follow) documentation outlines what activity you will see related to a followed user.

By the way, when specifying `followings` and `trackTerms` on the filter steam it's actually saying get me Tweets containing these terms *or* from these users. That's why you would see output when `trackTerms` was specified. This also goes for the additional `locations` parameter.